# How do I access a timer from within a Vulkan shader?

Tags: vulkan

In a Vulkan shader I want to query a timer so that I can query it twice at two points in my code and use the difference. For example, I want to convert the difference to a color so I can see a visualization of how long various pixels take.

I’m looking for something like the Cuda clock() intrinsic function.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Are you asking to find out how much time passes between two locations in a shader? Are you asking about how long it takes to execute a particular rendering operation? Try to be more specific about what you're doing.

Comment: @Nicol I’m looking for something like the Cuda clock() intrinsic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clockARB()` of the [ARB_shader_clock](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_clock.txt) GLSL extension. At Vulkan side uses [VK_KHR_shader_clock](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_KHR_shader_clock) extension.